# Winform: How to Collect All String Values from a ListBox

Tags: c#, winforms

I'd like to be able to collect all the string values in a Winform `ListBox`. At the moment my code loops through the `ListBox` and gets the values, but it's appending all values together in one long string:

```
private string GetFormNumberValues()
{
    string formNumbers = "";
    foreach (string item in this.lbFormNumbers.Items)
    {
        formNumbers += item.ToString();
    }
    return formNumbers;
}
```

How can I collect each individual string value to use for later? Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean for example you need all items in a comma separated string? Or in a `List<String>`?

Comment: Not comma-separated, just need to be able to collect the string individual values so I can later pass that collection to another method.

Comment: So you can use either of [adv12](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34095820/3110834) answer or [mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34095900/3110834).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
private string[] GetFormNumberValues()
{
    List<string> strings = new List<string>();
    foreach (string item in this.lbFormNumbers.Items)
    {
        strings.Add(item.ToString());
    }
    return strings.ToArray();
}
```

(Depending on your needs, you could simplify this by returning a `List` rather than an array...)

Comment: Using linq methods makes code simple and beautiful. Also it's easy to learn.

Answer (score 4):

You can have them in a List this way:

```
var list = listBox1.Items.Cast<object>().Select(x => x.ToString()).ToList();
```