# How many CheckBoxes are checked in the GroupBox?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm making a program that has to count how many `CheckBox` controls are checked, only in a `GroupBox`.

I've tried a lot of different ways but I can't get it work.

How can this be made?

```
// This is one of the many things I tried...        
public CheckBox rNum;
//This method is used on FormLoad.
public void CreateBoxes()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 36; i++)
    {
        rNum = new CheckBox();
        rNum.Text = i.ToString();

        //CheckBoxes added to flowLayoutPanel.
        flw.Controls.Add(rNum);
    }   
}

public int count;          
//This method is used on Button Click
public void CountIt()
{
    foreach (CheckBox box in groupBox.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>())
    {
        if (box.Checked)
        {
            count++;
        }
    }    
    MessageBox.Show(count.ToString());
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could say exactly what's not working.  Is the count too high?  Is the count zero?  Are the `CheckBoxes` immediate children of the `groupBox` or is there an intermediate `Panel` or something like that?

Comment: Note that you're not actually checking if the `CheckBox` is checked or not when you increment `count`....

Comment: You say in your comment on my answer that you create 75 `CheckBoxes` in the `Form`'s `Load` event handler.  To what control do you add them?  To `groupBox`?  Or to the `Form`?  Or to some other control?

Comment: Yea, i forgot to mention that they are added to flowLayoutPanel, Sorry for the fuss. im a bit sleepy so i forgot that i used flowLayout somehow...

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information if you wanna help

Comment: @Mizuchi, I've updated my answer to reflect the additional information in your comments.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a linq query like this:

```
var count = flw.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().Count(x=>x.Checked);
```

It returns count of `CheckBox` controls in flw which are checked.

Comment: It seems you need a correction in title, in code you said *//CheckBoxes added to flowLayoutPanel.* but in title you are asking for *Checkboxes in the GroupBox?*. Anyway, if they are hosted in any of the, use the query on that control simply.

Comment: the revelation of flw came in an edit to the original question.

Comment: @adv12 It seems the OP forgot to correct the title and description of question after edit. Probably they mean FlowLayoutPanel in title and description of question.

Comment: Right, but that is the OP's central point of confusion.  Basically he thought he was adding the CheckBoxes to a GroupBox but forgot that they were actually being added to an intermediate FlowLayoutPanel.  If he had fully realized the implications of this, his question would have been answered.

Comment: @adv12 It seems you tried to help them to understand the difference.

Comment: @adv12 By the way, it seems you didn't start to work with linq yet. [Did you?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34095783/winform-how-to-collect-all-string-values-from-a-listbox/34095900#comment55944036_34095900) ;)

Comment: Haha!  You got me!  Actually I have started to use it occasionally but not often enough that it's my go-to.  And in this case I was starting with the OP's code...

Comment: @Mizuchi Let me know if you have any question about the answer :)

Comment: @Mizuchi Btw, You can accept an answer by click on check mark near the answer. Also when you accept an answer, it would be great if you also vote for the answer by click on up arrow near the post. It's not compulsory at all, but it's common, reasonable and recommended. For more information about how does accepting answers work see this [post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow).

Comment: @Mizuchi Is't it what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments and the edits to your question, you need to be looking for your `CheckBoxes` in the `FlowLayoutPanel` to which you added them, not `groupBox`.  Given that your `FlowLayoutPanel` is called `flw`, do the following:

```
public void CountIt()
{
    foreach (CheckBox box in flw.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>())
    {
        if (box.Checked)
        {
            count++;
        }
    }

    MessageBox.Show(count.ToString());
}
```

Note that I'm increasing the count only when the `CheckBox` is checked, which is now reflected in your question.  Failing to do that check was a bug in your original code.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But this dose not somehow, i tried this before... The MessageBox always shows 0...

Comment: Then please provide the information I requested in my comment on the question.

Comment: I forgot the add that, there is about 35 checkbox's, so i created them in the formload using 'Checkbox chk = new CheckBox()' with a for loop.

Comment: It would be better to post that comment on the question itself so other potential answerers see it.